# How to get multiple checkbox values from modal form and populate in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I have a set of multiple checkboxes on a modal form and when the user selects submit on the form the checkbox values are saved to the table. This part is working great and if I refresh the webpage I can see the correct values. However, I would like to not have to refresh the webpage to see the values populated, for this I need to insert the values from the same JS function that is saving them to the table, but I'm not sure how to read the values from the modal form :(.

Here is my JS code which calls the python function to save the values to the database:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".containerProfile").on("click", "#saveCheckboxes", function() {
        var url = "/profile/updateCheckboxes";   

        csrftoken();  
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: url,
          data: $('#checkboxForm').serialize(),
        }).done(function(response){
            $("#modalCheckboxTest").modal("hide");

            //I want to modify the HTML here to display the checkbox values on the webpage
        });
    })
})
```

If I take a look at the serialized data that is sent to the database it looks something like "chk1=4.00&chk2=0.00". How can I loop through and read the value of each checkbox before it serialized?

Thanks for the help!

### EDIT:

I am trying to loop through all checkbox values and insert them into the HTML, the HTML might already contain those values so I want to clear them and insert only the new ones so it is up to date.

My HTML code looks like this;

```
<div id="ind">
  {% for inf in prospect.prospect_industries.all %}
    {% if inf.is_interested %}
      <div>
        <span id="industryInterest" data-fit="id_industry{{inf.id}}"></span>

        <p>{{inf.get_industry_display}}</p>
      </div>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

My JS looks like this:

```
 for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) { 
   //alert(response[i].industry + ":" + response[i].is_interested);

   if (response[i].is_interested) {

     $("#industryInterest").html(response[i].industry);
     $("#industryInterest").attr("data-fit", response[i].industry);
   }
 }
```

I tried to do something like this "$('#ind').html('');" however, that removes the HTML within the #ind div so then I am not able to insert the new values. What is the correct approach to update the HTML in this case?

Comment: Have you consoled out your response on the done function? What does it say?

Comment: @Taplar I've added the form markup. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @balapa Oh! Thanks for that idea! Instead of reading what is on the form itself I can read what the response is, that seems to work. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: @balapa maybe you can help me with something else? See the edit to my original post, I am not sure how I should go about inserting the updated checkbox values back into the HTML. Any ideas? Should I clear the html within the #ind div and then rebuild it using jQuery or is there another way?

Comment: After you get the response, clear up the whole container `$('#ind').html('');`.
Then insert `#ind` with the response data. You can use for loop here. Maybe look something like this

`done(function(response){
  $("#ind").html("");
  for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) { 
    $("#ind").append(response[i]);
  }
});`